# How to hide current location in google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have implemented Google Map in my project.

I want to hide the default current location marker (please refer to the attached Image).

However, I need to show the button which allows to go my current location (marked in the top right corner)

[image: I want to hide the blue icon from google map]

Answer (score 15):

You can disable it from with your Google Map instance (here called "map")

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This hides top right button(MyLocation button) too.

Comment: If you want to keep the button, you just have to remove the 2nd line :

map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

Comment: Still not working, Now both icons are gone. :(

Comment: Did you finally get an answer or find the solution to this ?
Thanks to share.

Comment: @Mario Finally i had remove current location and added custom my location button on the map.

Comment: Ok, well that's the thing. When you want custom stuff, do it yourself ;).
Actually I don't understand why they closed the topic as unclear. You could get it just by looking at the picture...
So thanks Jatin, this closes for real the topic ;).

Comment: Question seems quite clear. Answer is surely incorrect.

Comment: Anyway we could do this without adding custom location button?

Comment: we can also use this , it works for me ,
       GoogleMap(
                      myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                      myLocationEnabled: true,
                      zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                      zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                      trafficEnabled: true,
                      mapType: MapType.normal,