# Android Map - Hide/Replace "My Location" blue dot, but keep "My Location" Button

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android, google-maps-markers

my overall question/goal is to have an Android Google Map that displays the default "Locate me" button at the top-right corner but uses a custom marker on the map (not the blue dot) to visualize the users location. How to achieve that?

What I tried / researched so far:

1. I found no way just to **replace** the blue dot with a custom marker.
2. Another idea was to **hide** the blue dot but still show the "Locate me" button (and then put an ordinary custom marker at the users location on the map). But there seems to be no way to do that.

   - `map.setMyLocationEnabled(false / true);` toggles both blue dot AND button.
   - `map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false / true);` toggles just the button but needs `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` to work. But that makes the blue dot visible.
   - There seems no API call to hide the blue dot but keeps the button visible.
3. Last idea was to set `map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);` and put a custom buttom (and location marker) on the map. But I couldn't find a way to do that. Of course I could put a normal button beside/on top of the map control but for UX consistency I would not prefer this solution.

A similar question for approach 2) was asked here [How to hide current location in google map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29008384/797200) but as you can read in the comments the provided answer is wrong (I tried and can confirm).